# htaccess rewrite URL for dynamic content

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am wondering how would I change the url from:

```
single.php?id=1
```

to:

```
quote-1
```

Each submitted data has an id, of course. They can go to the URL, the id of the "quote" to get the quote. How would the URL rewrite look? I've tried to use tools online, but ether they didn't work or I didn't understand how to use it.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?  Is mod_rewrite enabled for your site/vhost?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beginner Url Rewrite htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337537/beginner-url-rewrite-htaccess)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the following your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule quote-(\d+) single.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

[mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)